# Dialogflow API access follow up intent in Python

Tags: python, api, dialogflow-es

I am following the following tutorial to understand Dialogflow Python API.

Here is how my adaptation looks:

```
import dialogflow_v2 as dialogflow
import json
from google.api_core.exceptions import InvalidArgument
from google.oauth2 import service_account

dialogflow_key = json.load(open(r'path_to_json_file.json'))
credentials = (service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_info(dialogflow_key))
session_client = dialogflow.SessionsClient(credentials=credentials)


DIALOGFLOW_LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-US'
DIALOGFLOW_PROJECT_ID = 'some_project_id'
SESSION_ID = 'current-user-id'
session = session_client.session_path(DIALOGFLOW_PROJECT_ID, SESSION_ID)

text_to_be_analyzed =  "mobile data"
text_input = dialogflow.types.TextInput(text=text_to_be_analyzed, language_code=DIALOGFLOW_LANGUAGE_CODE)
query_input = dialogflow.types.QueryInput(text=text_input)
try:
    response = session_client.detect_intent(session=session, query_input=query_input)
except InvalidArgument:
    raise

print("Query text:", response.query_result.query_text)
print("Detected intent:", response.query_result.intent.display_name)
print("Detected intent confidence:", response.query_result.intent_detection_confidence)
print("Fulfillment text:", response.query_result.fulfillment_text)
```

Here is what program outputs:

```
Query text: mobile data
Detected intent: support.problem
Detected intent confidence: 0.41999998688697815
Fulfillment text: Make sure mobile data is enabled and Wi-Fi is turned off.
```

Now my intent `support.problem` has follow up intent `support.problem-yes`, where customer replies `Done it` and gets back another response `Let us try another step`

How do I pass text/query to follow up intent and how do I get response in Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `response.query_result` object should also contain an `output_context` field, which should be an array of Context objects. This array should be passed in [`query_parameters.context`](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow-enterprise/docs/reference/rest/v2/projects.agent.sessions/detectIntent#QueryParameters) you pass to `detect_intent()`.

You should be able to create a dictionary with the query parameters fields (including one for `context`) that you pass to `session_client.detect_intent`.

Comment: `session_client.detect_intent` accepts `query_params`, but how do I access `query_parameters.context` for passing `response.query_result.output_contexts`?

Comment: You should be able to use a dictionary. Answer clarified.

Comment: Thank you! Here is what I ended up doing: `qp = dialogflow.types.QueryParameters(contexts = response.query_result.output_contexts)` and then `response_1 = session_client.detect_intent(session = session, query_params=qp, query_input = query_input_1)`, where `query_input_1` is new query with `Done it` in it. It all worked, and likely I did not have to create additional object for `contexts`